# Signing out of Outlook on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-outlook

How can I sign out of Outlook on a PC with Windows 8?

A previous answer says:

> Convert your account to a LOCAL ACCOUNT (using PC settings in lower right-hand corner) "This will convert your account to a local one, which will disable all or most of the calling home requirements."

What is a Local Account?  What is meant by "the calling home requirements"?

On my Windows Vista, there is a signout at the upper right-hand corner; this is not there on Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of Windows 8 user accounts:

- Those that are tied to a **Microsoft account** (in the form of an email address). These accounts sync information from your account (documents, settings, emails, etc) to the cloud. You can sign in to your Microsoft account from anywhere and access this information
- **Local accounts** are the typical user account that would find on Windows 7 or Windows Vista. Nothing from this account is synced with the cloud unless you use third-party software.

---

The reason you are unable to sign out of Outlook is because it is tied in with your Microsoft user account. When you sign in to your computer, you are signing into all the services that such an account provides. Converting this to a local account will discontinue these services and allow you to locally sign into and out of them at will.

---

For more info you can go to [Microsoft's explanation](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-user-account#create-user-account=windows-8) of the two account types.